# Wavy lines throughout print

Tags: y-axis, hardware

I have a zonestar P802QR2 model. This problem has been appearing since I first started using it and I'd really appreciate some help here!

The prints always come out wavy and I'm guessing the y-axis is the main problem since the wavy lines come out stronger when moving in certain directions. The worst is when its moving towards the +ve y-direction.

[image: single layer print]

I printed an octagon outline here to show the difference for different directions. The problem appears regardless of the speed setting. (ignore the poor taping, it doesn't affect the current problem)

Thanks!

Comment: stick a small container of water on the corner of bed. When it's moving in the +ve direction does the water generate waves or does it just slosh around? (think bubble level)

Comment: Belts tight? Binding bed platform?

Comment: @user77232 i can't call them waves but the +ve movement causes more of small vibrations while the -ve is just sloshing. what does this mean?